# How to route map between two distinct points?

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

I feel that this must be a common and easy feature on the iPhone. I am looking for the ability to map between two distinct points on the iPhone by thumbtack.

I understand you can do it via explicit address, but this is not often at hand and this method runs against several use cases (e.g. Mapping run route).

How to do this?

Comment: Telling, that Apple would remove a perfectly good feature. The techno geeks of the world assume that those of us who like using apps in ‘traditional’ ways are mere Luddites, unworthy of the few bytes of programming necessary to allow us to continue to use (and think, and conceive of) processes as we always have. Thanks a lot.

Comment: my apologies on the sarcasm and frustration shared earlier, corrected now. I was referencing the existing Google Maps web API, this is clean and standardized in my opinion I recommend this. My apologies again for the earlier sarcasm.

Answer (score 3):

1. Drop a pin and add the location to your bookmarks.
2. Drop another pin and tap the directions button.
3. Select the first location as the location in your bookmarks and the second location should already be set to the second dropped pin location.

Answer (score 0):

My final method.

1. Open location A, copy the address.
2. Open location B
3. Click 'Directions to Here'
4. Paste into 'Start' location A. Done!

I dislike that Apple does not have a feature set to address this and recommend its addition if possible.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done for walking routes etc in iOS 16.1 and maybe other iOS':

1. In Maps, create two or more **Favourites**.
2. Select a Favourite. A route is created between it and your current location.
3. Change travel method to **Drive**.
4. Select **Add Stop**.
5. Select another Favourite.
6. Select and hold **My Location**, then select **Delete**.
7. Change travel method to **Walk**.